# Failed to fetch Trusty binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.14.197 80]

Tags: ubuntu

using: apt-get update

results:
Failed to fetch http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 138.201.14.197 80]

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
Arch:           Intel/i386

Date:           Jan 16, 2019

~$ tor --version
Tor version 0.3.4.9 (git-074ca2e0054fded1).

I believe that the binary path (and files) has been deleted from repository.

Question: is this a repository network/server problem or is this a quiet way to stop supporting for i386 ?

Comment: and whats the question?

Comment: thank you, the question did not show up in the first post attempt.

Comment: i don't think they are phasing out `i386` support. they provide builds (stable, experimental and nightly) for `i386`, `amd64`, `arm64`, `armel` and even `armhf`, but @SEdude indeed `trusty` packages are completely missing!

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. Browsing around the repository I don't see the trusty directory at all. Meanwhile, https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en still claims for trusty:

> You need to add the following entries to /etc/apt/sources.list or a
>   new file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/:
>
> deb https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org trusty main deb-src
>   https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org trusty main

@DJCrashdummy to your comment, my question is what happened to the repository & packages for trusty? Are they no longer being supported by the tor team despite the OS still receiving support from Canonical through April 2019?

Comment: I still do not know if this is caused by a manual install, instead for a ubuntu repository installation.  Or a repository failure when I was updating my system. I am still checking.

Comment: @JohnBR well... the error is not on your side. - your options are either [reach somehow out to the tor-project](https://www.torproject.org/about/contact.html), report that `trusty` builds are missing and wait/hope for the builds, or (which is the more sustained solution) consider an upgrade to (at least) `xenial` because `trusty` support is running out anyway in 2 months (april 2019).

Comment: @DJCrashdummy my tests here indicate several possibilities (like you have already noted too), but yesterday the self update of the tor app did update (ie. pop-up showing update available, I agreed, download progress completed and update did finish).  But as SEdude noted the ppa/repository still is missing.

Comment: @DJCrashdummy and yes, the update is inevitable (as borgs saying: "resistance is futile"), but I am doing tests on my laptop (with a new SSD) bionic beaver (18.04.1), most is OK, "snap" is a "snap" but uses many resources (with SSD we again have to plan storage space) worst is having to get back to gnome GUI, mouse and key shortcuts....takes time, and patience, not to mention systemctl.